# Bootstrap Button Link Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Button Link Not Working see code below:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <a href="home.aspx?Id=146">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn">Button Link</button>             
      </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I use firebug for development, is there an easy place to see what javascript events are attached and to which objects such as this button class? find it hard to debug as don't know what code is being called and on what events for bootstrap and other external js files

Comment: why do you need a button inside an anchor tag? simply add the "btn btn-primary" classes to the anchor tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or, you can just use a link which looks like a button..

```
<a href="home.aspx?Id=146" class="btn btn-primary">Button Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `a` tag and add `window.location.href` to button `onclick`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn" 
        onclick="window.location.href='home.aspx?Id=146'; return false;">
        Button Link
</button>
```

Comment: I thought that we were supposed to avoid mixing javascript with the html?